# Linq Update with large number of fields

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table that has about 100 different fields. I have an MVC view to make edits and changes to a specific instance. Some of the 100 fields will change, some of them won't. Is there a way to make these changes without manually typing out each field? Here is my code so far

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(z => z.Exception));

    ViewBag.Error = errors;

    return View("~/Views/errorE.cshtml");
}

try
{
    Phone selectedItem = (from x in DB.Phones
                          where x.PhoneID == ID
                          select x).Single();

    //UPDATE MODEL//

    DB.SubmitChanges();
    ViewBag.Status = "Update Succesfull.";
    TempData["Toastr"] = "Success";
    return View("~/Views/PhoneCatalog/edit.cshtml", _PhoneCatalog);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ViewBag.Error = e.Message;

    return View("~/Views/errorE.cshtml");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `TryUpdateModel()` to get the model binder automatically update your entity object with the posted form fields with matching names.

The line you should add is:

```
//UPDATE MODEL
TryUpdateModel(selectedItem);
```

Please beware of the security implications and make sure you are not creating a [Mass Assignment Vulnerability](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Comment: The changes dont save

Comment: Are your form names matching the properties of the entity? Typically you would want your view to use the entity type as the model for this to work.

Comment: Form fields match. The view uses the same model type

Answer (score 0):

External libraries like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) are popular for this, otherwise one "poor man's way" is to use the method `SetValues` from your dbContext object.

```
DB.Entry(copyToObject).CurrentValues.SetValues(copyFromObject);
```

This will copy any properties where the property names match each other, so it's meant to be used with a DTO.